# Ubuntu installation stuck in middle

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, system-installation, usb-installation, boot-partition

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my blank HDD, so I formatted it and (after much stumbling around buttons and settings not knowing what they meant) I think I created an EFI NTFS partition 512 MiB and the rest of the 500 GB NTFS (I realize that NTFS is I think only for Windows, but it was saying I couldn't install Ubuntu because "there is no root file system specified" - or something to that effect). The installer let me finally start the process on the HDD, and after it got to "creating EXT4 file system for / in partition number 5 of SCSI4 (0,1,0) (sda)..." it seemed like it has been going nowhere for the past 6 hours. To make matters worse, I carelessly ignored the file checking message at startup that my live usb "has 18 files damaged. You may experience errors" in a fit of overtiredness and optimism from being up for 9 hours trying to get it to install on this HDD. The logs are below. Is it actually progressing? If not, what steps can I take to solve it? If I power it down, will it corrupt the HDD?

Here are the logs as far back as I can get them (I am not sure they are since the beggining of being powered on): https://justpaste.it/7mnqj

Comment: Download a new .iso and write it to USB again. After that, you can just pick 'erase' during the install process and it takes care of all the partitioning for you.

Comment: @KGIII but how do I get it out out of installing? Just turn off the computer? Won't that corrupt the HDD?

Comment: It will only corrupt the data on the hard drive. That's immaterial because you'll be writing new data to the disk. So, yes. Just go ahead and force a reboot.